# Filter data with specific pattern on following line in R

Tags: r, filter

I have data set that shows below:

```
ID, Colour
1, Red
1, Yellow
1, Blue
1, Green
1, Pink
1, Red
1, Yellow
1, Blue
1, Red
1, Red
2, Red
2, Yellow
2, Blue
2, Blue
2, Yellow
2, Red
2, Blue
2, Red
2, Red
3, Blue
3, Blue
3, Red
3, Red
3, Yellow
3, Blue
3, Red
3, Yellow
3, Blue
```

I want to filter the row, which consists of this pattern of Red, Yellow, Blue.

The result should be like this, with the index of each pattern:

```
ID, Colour, Index
        1, Red, 1
        1, Yellow, 1
        1, Blue, 1
        1, Red, 2
        1, Yellow, 2
        1, Blue, 2
        2, Red, 3
        2, Yellow, 3
        2, Blue, 3
        3, Red, 4
        3, Yellow, 4
        3, Blue, 4
        3, Red, 5
        3, Yellow, 5
        3, Blue, 5
```

Thank you in advance, hopefully, anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data.table approach, that uses `Reduce` and `shift` to find the IDs that have the pattern

```
library(data.table)

out = setDT(d)[Reduce(paste, shift(Colour,0:-2))=="Red Yellow Blue"]
out = out[,index:=.I][rep(1:.N,3)][, Colour:=rep(c("Red", "Yellow", "Blue"), length.out=.N)]

       ID Colour index
    <int> <char> <int>
 1:     1    Red     1
 2:     1 Yellow     2
 3:     2   Blue     3
 4:     3    Red     4
 5:     3 Yellow     5
 6:     1   Blue     1
 7:     1    Red     2
 8:     2 Yellow     3
 9:     3   Blue     4
10:     3    Red     5
11:     1 Yellow     1
12:     1   Blue     2
13:     2    Red     3
14:     3 Yellow     4
15:     3   Blue     5
```

Another good way to do this is create a function, `f` that creates the output, given some ids

```
f <- function(id) {
  data.table(
    ID = rep(id,each=3),
    Colour=rep(c("Red", "Yellow","Blue"),times=length(id)),
    index=rep(1:length(id), times=3))
}
```

Just get the ids, using the above strategy

```
ids = setDT(d)[Reduce(paste, shift(Colour,0:-2))=="Red Yellow Blue"]$ID
```

and apply to the function

```
f(ids)

       ID Colour index
    <int> <char> <int>
 1:     1    Red     1
 2:     1 Yellow     2
 3:     1   Blue     3
 4:     1    Red     4
 5:     1 Yellow     5
 6:     1   Blue     1
 7:     2    Red     2
 8:     2 Yellow     3
 9:     2   Blue     4
10:     3    Red     5
11:     3 Yellow     1
12:     3   Blue     2
13:     3    Red     3
14:     3 Yellow     4
15:     3   Blue     5
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    slice(sort(unique(rep(which(rollapply(Colour, width = 3,
       FUN = toString) == "Red, Yellow, Blue"), each = 3) + 0:2))) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(Index = cumsum(Colour == "Red"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 3
      ID Colour Index
   <int> <chr>  <int>
 1     1 Red        1
 2     1 Yellow     1
 3     1 Blue       1
 4     1 Red        2
 5     1 Yellow     2
 6     1 Blue       2
 7     2 Red        3
 8     2 Yellow     3
 9     2 Blue       3
10     3 Red        4
11     3 Yellow     4
12     3 Blue       4
13     3 Red        5
14     3 Yellow     5
15     3 Blue       5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L), Colour = c("Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Green", "Pink", 
"Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue", 
"Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Red", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", 
"Red", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue")), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.